# how to create a textbox in ssrs for user entry as a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that has three params. one is dropdown. It created automatically when i supplied 
name and value, Then If we select multivalue, it shows multivalue dropdownlist.

But I am not able to create a textbox. That will act as a parameter to be supplied in report.

for that I have created a parameter, set it to allow null and datatype = "text" . 
parameter visibility is also visible but as a result I can see a textbox which is a disbled one.

How can this textbox be made to work?

Comment: In design mode, if you set a parameter to allow null, it will default check the allow null box when you preview the report. This will disable the text box until you uncheck the `allow null` box. Is this the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Actually I am trying to create a simple textbox in report where user can manually enter name in order to search records. I am able to draw dropdown and multi -select dropdown but not textbox.

Comment: I'm confused on what you are saying. Can you post an image of what you are trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: be aware that if you have other required parameters that are not completed before your text box, then the text box will be disabled. Have you tried filling in any other parameters first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in the Report Parameter Properties for the text field in question, chose Allow blank value (rather than Allow null value). In the Default Values section of the properties dialog, choose Specify values, Add a blank default value.

Now you will have a working text field that the end user can type into, and you can use that value for searches in your query.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To allow user to enter the parameter value manually:

1. Right click on the parameter and select **Parameter Properties**
2. On the **Available Values** tab, select **None**
3. Click **OK**

Now users can manually type in the parameter value.

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKcyD.png)